# Static web design = Photoshop, animated web design =?

Tags: website-design, animation

I'm a project manager and I want to hire people to design a new website.

For typical websites without animation, I hire Photoshop specialists and receive deliverables as .psd.

But this time I'm looking for a design that would have custom animated elements, like animated characters.

What kind of specialist should I hire for this, and what apps/formats are industry standard for animated web design?

Comment: [There are too many to list](https://www.google.com/search?q=animated+mockup+software&oq=animated+mockup+software&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.3954j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). This is not a good type of question for StackExchance sites.

Comment: @ZachSaucier I was asking about industry standard.

Comment: There is no industry standard.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch, Adobe XD, Affinity Designer, zeplin, figma, Mockflow, balsamiq, Flinto... even Adobe Animate all apply.